# Redis doesn't work on docker: Failed to read response from the server

Tags: docker, redis

Once Redis is started/restarted it works properly; hovewer, after some time it stops working. Yet in logs the following is seen:

```
1:S 11 Nov 2022 08:32:57.889 * Connecting to MASTER xxxxx:xxxx
1:S 11 Nov 2022 08:32:57.889 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 11 Nov 2022 08:32:58.025 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 11 Nov 2022 08:32:58.164 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 11 Nov 2022 08:32:58.164 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
```

(the IP has been hidden in terms of safety)

Redis is started through the docker with a standart configuration.

In what way this error can be solved?

I tried to set password, but this didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed just with enabled protected_mode and password